Unable to use physical partitions although using partition key in Azure Cosmos DB
We are using Azure Cosmos DB, Azure Cosmos SDK v3.35.4, .NET Core 7.
In our data, one of the columns values is distinct number like 1, 2, 3, 4, ...., 7869, ...., 34562, 34563,...  So we created a 'range' property in our C# model class which represent range.
Example 1-1000 is range = 1, 1001-2000 is range = 2 etc.
Example:

We insert this 'range' property in cosmos container as well and defined it as PartitionKey too. Means for CRUD operations we use this PartitionKey as well

We checked our Azure Cosmos DB insights in the Azure Portal for our container:


ONLY 1 physical partition is being used? What did I do wrong in selecting my partition key?

Data is split into logical partitions based on a partition key. Physical partitions are added when:

the RU/sec needs for your container approaches / goes beyond maximum supported by a physical partition (10K RU/sec)
the capacity needs for your container approaches / goes beyond a single physical partition (50GB)

Assuming you have very little data in your container, and your RU/sec is lower than 10,000, all of your logical partitions would fit in a single physical partition (which is why you're only seeing 1 physical partition).
When one (or both) of the two thresholds are exceeded, then your logical partitions will be distributed across multiple physical partitions.

Yes both conditions are not yet true for me, agree with your response
